# Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::purchases does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I am trying to follow this error but I don't know where it is that I need to create purchases. If someone could please help me know how to follow this error I would appreciate it.

Here is my Migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('purchases', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('product');
      $table->string('fname');
      $table->string('lname');
      $table->string('address');
      $table->string('city');
      $table->string('state');
      $table->integer('zip');
      $table->string('card');
      $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Here is my Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Purchase extends Model
{
  public function addPurchase($body)
  {
    $this->purchases()->create(compact('fName'));
    $this->purchases()->create(compact('lName'));
    $this->purchases()->create(compact('address'));
    $this->purchases()->create(compact('city'));
    $this->purchases()->create(compact('state'));
    $this->purchases()->create(compact('zip'));
    $this->purchases()->create(compact('card'));
  }
}
```

edit: I am trying to push all the above date to a mySQL database

Here is my controller store function

```
public function store(Purchase $purchase)
{
   $this->validate(request(), ['fName' => 'required|min:3']);
   $this->validate(request(), ['lName' => 'required|min:3']);
   $this->validate(request(), ['address' => 'required']);
   $this->validate(request(), ['city' => 'required']);
   $this->validate(request(), ['state' => 'required']);
   $this->validate(request(), ['zip' => 'required']);
   $this->validate(request(), ['card' => 'required']);

   $purchase->addPurchase(request('fName'));
   $purchase->addPurchase(request('lName'));
   $purchase->addPurchase(request('address'));
   $purchase->addPurchase(request('city'));
   $purchase->addPurchase(request('state'));
   $purchase->addPurchase(request('zip'));
   $purchase->addPurchase(request('card'));

   return back();
}
```

Comment: What's the desired behaviour? You get the error because within the model `Purchase` you're calling `$this->purchases()`, which does not exist. There's no method `purchases` on the model.

Comment: $body is an array with all the form's value, right?

Comment: @devk I thought that was what this line did. Schema::create('purchases', function (Blueprint $table) { it says 'purchases' is that not the variable?

Comment: Nope, it says method `purchases()` doesn't exist on the query builder. `$this` in the context of a Model will return a query builder, unless you instantiate a model (with something like `Model::first()`). Edit your question and explain what is the desired behavior and what is the `$body` variable and we can help you with that.

Comment: @devk the desired behavior is that everything in the form will push to a mySQL database. I am not sure how to check the $body variable (very new to laravel)

Comment: Can you post the code where you're using the `->addPurchase()` method? And what you're passing into it.

Comment: That's in my model. which is above.

Comment: It's defined there, but you're calling it somewhere else. Probably in a controller.

Comment: Oops sorry! I'll add it to the original question above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169522/discussion-between-landon-call-and-devk).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we've established in the comments, the error happens because `$purchase` variable in the controller is an instance of a `Purchase` query builder. And in your `->addPurchase() {...}` method you're calling `$this->purchase()`, which is a nonexistant method on a query builder.

Now how to make this work. There's a lot of ways.

One would be to manually assign all properties to the model and call `->save()` afterwards:

```
public function store(Purchase $purchase)
{
    // ... validation

    // Assign the properties
    $purchase->fname = request('fName');
    $purchase->lname = request('lName');
    $purchase->address = request('address');
    $purchase->city = request('city');
    $purchase->state = request('state');
    $purchase->zip = request('zip');
    $purchase->card = request('card');
    $purchase->save(); // Save to the database

    return back();
}
```

Another would be to use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment):

```
public function store(Purchase $purchase)
{
    // ... validation

    $purchase->forceCreate(request()->only([
        'fName', 'lName', 'address', 'city', 'state', 'zip', 'card',
    ]));

    return back();
}
```

Using `forceCreate(...)`, which is same as `->create(...)` except that it bypasses the `$fillable` array, which in this specific instance is OK, since a) we're manually telling it which fields are to be filled, with `request()->only([fields])` b) you're performing validation before saving.

And there are more ways to do this, most of them [well documented](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models).

One last thing I would recommend is to perform validation with (technically) 1 line:

```
public function store(Purchase $purchase)
{      
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'fName' => 'required|min:3',
        'lName' => 'required|min:3',
        'address' => 'required',
        'city' => 'required',
        'zip' => 'required',
        'card' => 'required',
    ]);

    // Save the model...
}
```

This way you would get all the errors (if something doesn't pass) in an array, rather than only the first one that didn't pass.

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip about all the errors I was wondering why I was only getting the "first" error!